# Implementing List<E>: do I need a new class?

Tags: java, list, implementation

First of all, i have been studying Java for only the last couple of weeks, so I don't have much experience yet.

This is more of a theoretical question. 
I want to create a simple list.

So first I made a class where I specified some methods. I want it to be generic so I can use any type.

```
  public interface List<E>
```

Now i need to implement it, so i created:

```
    public class MyList<E> implements List<E>
```

Now, I need two attributes:

```
 private E element;
 private MyList<E> next;
```

One will hold my generic type, the other will be the link to the next element.
First of all, I don't know if it's the correct way to write it. And if i leave this attributes inside this class, will it work properly?

Second of all, I have been thinking whether it's better to create another class, lets say a `Box` class, that will contain these two fields, thus making manipulation easier during my implementation.

Might be a silly question, but I am trying to learn and to understand the best ways to do this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to add that `List` does not already contain?

Comment: This is not List from java.util.*
this is my own list with my own methods. And just trying to get the hang of it with example from class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are trying to implement a singly-linked list. Now to answer your question, I think that it would be beneficial for you to create a `Box` class like you mentioned (often called `Node`). So your implementation might look like this:

```
public class MyList<E> implements List<E> {
    private Node<E> head;

    private static class Node<E> {
        private E element;
        private Node<E> next;

        public Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

`MyList` would hold a single `Node` that is connected to a chain of other `Node`s. If you [take a look](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html), this is how the the actual `java.util.LinkedList` class is written.

Comment: thats all i needed to know. thank! 
now a quick question, creating a class inside, how does that work? is it similar to creating another .java file and creating a public class Node. Or this class Node is only visible to MyList<E> ?

Comment: Try reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) and see if it clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a list has nodes that holds the elements. For example:

```
public class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;
}
```

Secondly, you need to define a root node but from this on you have two ways of implementing it:

- let the node implement the List interface or inherit the Node element and let this implement the interface
- create a class that implements your interface and holds the root element (common approach)

I will explain the second way because it's the usual way.
We need a "main class":

```
public class MyList<E> implements List<E> {
    private Node<E> root;
}
```

This class should now implement your methods and work on the root object - e.g. traverse through the nodes using the next pointer of the root node and so on.
Furthermore, usually the last node is saved too for faster adding and also the current size is stored - therefore, you need two more variables in your List implementation.

However, the Node class should now be a private inner class!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use your list, there are standard implementations in the `java.util`-package: [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for example. If you want to read something about different types of lists and the way of their implementation, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is always a good startingpoint.